# Singleton getinstance() method with void as return type

Tags: singleton

greetings.

I wrote the singleton class as shown below.

```
#include  <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Singleton
{

 private:
 static bool inst;

 static Singleton * ptr;
 Singleton()
 {
    cout<<"Singleton Private Constructor is called"<<endl;
 }

 public:
 static Singleton * Create_Instance()
 {
    if(!inst)
    {
        ptr = new Singleton();
        inst = true;
        cout<<"New instance is created"<<endl;
     }
    return ptr;
}
```

};

```
bool Singleton::inst = false;
Singleton * Singleton::ptr = NULL;

int main()
{
    Singleton * point = Singleton::Create_Instance();

    return 0;
}
```

Here the Singleton instance is returned to main from Create_Instance() method.

Here my is what if the return value of Create_Instance() is void ? Meaning if the signature is going to be "**static void Create_Instance()**", then how we will get the instance of Singleton in main.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: A return type of void explicitly indicates that the function returns nothing. Why do you want to do this from a factory method?

Comment: Yes return type of void conveys that the function returns nothing. My objective is to create the object inside the "static void Create_Instance()" method and collect the object in the main somehow.

Comment: Your existing code is giving you the pointer to the created instance as you describe. In what way is what you are getting from the code as-is unsuitable for what you're trying to do?

Comment: 1.With the help of "static void Create_Instance()" method i should create the object of Singleton class.
2.In main i should get that crated instance somehow (with out return value)
3. This is what my expectation.
4. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You'll need either a return value, or a method that takes a modifiable reference as an argument to get the value out, or (perhaps less advisedly) just make the instance a global. I don't understand though, why a return is unacceptable for what you're trying to do?